# json manipulation and push to mongodb (PLAY-2.7-Scala-2.12)

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

anyone can help me out how to **convert** a *model* ( like a user (name: string ))to **JSON** and *save it to MongoDB* ??

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this..

Build.sbt :

```
"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.6.0"
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.1"
```

First Create mongoDB configuration..

```
val credential: MongoCredential = ???
val settings: MongoClientSettings = ???
val client: MongoClient = MongoClient(settings)
val db: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("db-name")
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = client.getCollection("collection-name")

case class Model(name: string)

object Model {
    implicit val modelFormat: Format[Model] = Json.format[Model]
}
```

Usage:

```
val data: JsValue = Json.toJson(new Model("Rex"))
```

Insert into db and check if inserted :) ..

```
collection.insertOne(Document(data.toString))
```

Comment: val data: JsonNode = Json.toJson(new Book("ISBN100","TEST" , "LEL" , 12,9999))
    collection.insertOne(Document(data.toString))
intellij shows this error in editor : 
[ERROR] : cannot resolve overloaded methode insertone
[ERROR] : unspecified value parameters:documents:seq[_<:Book]

Comment: well i m trying to make an api 
def addBook = Action { implicit request: Request[Book]  =>
//    val newBook = request.body
//    val books = bookService.addBook(newBook)
//    collection.insertOne(newBook)
//
//
//  }

Comment: setup for the connection to mongodb like this: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4/getting-started/

Comment: I think you just need to check your `val newBook = request.body` it must be a JSON formatted String. because Document need String parameter but in JSON format.